# Controlling the border thickness of the tables in LyX

Tags: lyx

Is it possible to control the border thickness of the tables in LyX? In the LyX [documentation](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Tables) it written:

> `\arrayrulewidth` is the thickness of the cell border line, the default
>   is `0.4 pt`.

But I don't seem to understand how to user `\arrayrulewidth`. not really familiar with LaTeX. Is it possible to increase the thickness of the borders (make the more bold) in LyX? Also, I read some previous threads but they all solved the problem with LaTeX and not with LyX.

Answer (score 1):

Place your cursor somewhere in your document before your table. Then press <kbd>Ctrl + L</kbd> (or go to Insert > TeX Code) and then paste `\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.5pt}` into it. You can experiment with the 1.5, increasing or decreasing it.